# How to hide text when typing in inputDialog

Tags: java, user-interface, input, dialog

```
if(e.getSource() == credLimit){ // event handling for user to change credit limit
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");
    input.setEchoChar('*'); <<-----here is what I have tried
    if(input.equals(password)) { // password check for credit limit
        double credLimitTotal = Double.parseDouble(changeCredLimit.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, currentCreditCard.changeCreditLimit(credLimitTotal));
        changeCredLimit.setText("");
    }
}
```

So, I am looking to hide the text from the inputdialog, `setEchoChar` does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide characters directly in an `InputDialog`. You can create your own `Dialog` by using a [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html), which hides characters by default. Try out this code:

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();

JLabel jl = new JLabel("Password: ");
box.add(jl);

JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField(24);
box.add(jpf);

int button = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, box, "Enter your password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

if (button == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    char[] input = jpf.getPassword();
    if(input.equals(password)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Use [`setEchoChar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29) to change the character displayed to the user while typing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide text from the text box you need to use JPassword like this

```
passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
passwordField.setActionCommand(OK);
```

Here is the link to for more details

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

Answer (score -2):

This will hide the text as you entered it.

```
<input type="password" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
```

Comment: This is HTML, not Java